# Open zip files in nested directories fails with "unexpected token" error

Tags: powershell, foreach, zip, piping

I have a script that I am trying to get to sort through a directory and open all the zip files and store the text files all to one directory. Here is the code:

```
#Script to open zip files in tree

New-Item E:\Files -type directory

Get-ChildItem -Path E:\SNL_Insurance\* -Recurse -Exclude "*.md5"|
    ForEach-Object {
        $file = $_
        write-host $file;
        $destination = "E:\Files"
        $shell = New-Object -com shell.application
        $zip = $shell.NameSpace($file) |
               foreach($item in $_.items()){
                   $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item)
               }
    }
```

I think I almost have it, but keep getting this error (any elaboration on piping would be helpful):

```
Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statement.
At E:\Expand-ZIPFile.ps1:14 char:19
+         foreach($item in <<<<  $_.items()){
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (in:String) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

EDIT:
Ahh... thanks for that distinction. I made your edits but after each of my "write-host" checks to see the file name I get the following error: 
`You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At E:\Expand-ZIPFile.ps1:14 char:30 + foreach($item in $zip.items <<<< ()){ + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (items:String) [], RuntimeException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

EDIT2: So the original code does copy files to a new directory but also copies the whole zip file over. I tried to add an if statement to only copy files that are .txt but the code just steps through each directory without copying anything. If you have any idea that would be appreciated as I have exhausted all my ideas. Here is the code:

```
 new-Item E:\Files -type directory

 Get-Childitem -path E:\SNL_Insurance\* -recurse -exclude "*.md5" |

 Foreach-object {

    $file = $_
    write-host $file;
    $destination = "E:\Files"
    $shell = new-object -com shell.application
    $zip = $shell.NameSpace($file.Fullname) 
    foreach($item in $zip.items()){

        if ($item.Extension -eq ".txt") {
            $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers you are too helpful! i'm new to this powershell jazz

Comment: done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172579/only-copy-certain-file-types-after-unzipping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing [`foreach` with `ForEach-Object` loops](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/07/08/getting-to-know-foreach-and-foreach-object.aspx). The former neither read from nor do they write to pipelines. Also, `$file` is a [`FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object, not a path. The [`NameSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method expects a path string, so you need to use `$file.FullName`.

Replace

```
$zip = $shell.NameSpace($file) |
       foreach($item in $_.items()){
           $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item)
       }
```

with

```
$zip = $shell.NameSpace($file.FullName)

foreach($item in $zip.items()){
    $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item)
}
```