# Only copy certain file types after unzipping

Tags: powershell

I have the following code to unzip many folders in a directory tree:

```
new-Item E:\Files -type directory

Get-Childitem -path E:\SNL_Insurance\* -recurse -exclude "*.md5" |

Foreach-object {

    $file = $_
    write-host $file;
    $destination = "E:\Files"
    $shell = new-object -com shell.application
    $zip = $shell.NameSpace($file.Fullname) 

    foreach($item in $zip.items()){

        if ($item.name -eq ".txt") {
            $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item)
        }
    }

}
```

Without the if statement the script copies the zip files over too, not just the text files contained beneath. I thought I could check to make sure the file extension was .txt (or *.txt ive tried both) but $item.name doesn't seem to contain what i thought it did. If you have any ideas and/or can explain the $shell variable here (and specifically $shell.Namespace that would be very helpful) thanks in advance.

EDIT: Thanks for the responses. I actually found another way to do it before I saw these answers. Here is the solution I found if anyone is interested:

```
new-Item E:\Files -type directory

Get-Childitem -path E:\SNL_Insurance\Insurance\* -recurse -exclude "*.md5"|

Foreach-object {

    if ($_.extension -eq ".zip") {
        Get-Childitem -path $_ -recurse| 

            Foreach-object {

                    $file = $_
                    write-host $file;
                    $destination = "E:\Files"
                    $shell = new-object -com shell.application
                    $zip = $shell.NameSpace($file.Fullname) 

                    foreach($item in $zip.items()){

                        $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item)

                    }

            }       


    }
}
```

Comment: You're probably looking for `$item.extension`

Comment: @RyanBemrose `FolderItem` objects don't have such a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to copy just the text files you can use:

```
foreach($item in $zip.items()){
if ($item.Type -eq 'Text Document') {
        $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item)
    }
}
```

OR

```
$zip.items() | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq 'Text Document'} | 
    Foreach-Object { $shell.NameSpace($Destination).copyhere($_)}
```

how did i know to use the `type` property? I used:

```
$zip.items()
```

to look all the properties that are available to use.

Comment: It might be simpler to just look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787810%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). ;)

Comment: he he that's true :) ...there is a lot of good information available on MSDN, but we dont check it often...thx @AnsgarWiechers

Answer (score 0):

The [`Items()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method enumerates [`FolderItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787810%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) objects, which (unlike `FileInfo` objects) don't have an `Extension` property. You can do a wildcard match with the [`-like`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) operator:

```
foreach ($item in $zip.Items()) {
    if ($item.Name -like '*.txt') {
        $shell.NameSpace($destination).copyhere($item)
    }
}
```

or (as [@Kiran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31174543/1630171) has suggested) check the type of the object:

```
foreach ($item in $zip.Items()) {
    if ($item.Type -eq 'text document') {
        $shell.NameSpace($destination).copyhere($item)
    }
}
```